# SugarCRM customization of Basic template

Tags: templates, sugarcrm

I need to add a field in `basic template`. Can anyone help me how can i add another field in `include/SugarObjects/templates/basic/vardefs.php` in upgrade safe manner.

In `VardefManager's function addTemplate` not like general standards of Sugar it is not requiring the custom paths

`include/SugarObjects/VardefManager.php` near line 107 `SugarCE6.5.5`:

```
   if(empty($templates[$template])){
        $path = 'include/SugarObjects/templates/' . $template . '/vardefs.php';
        if(file_exists($path)){
            require($path);
            $templates[$template] = $vardefs;
        }else{
            $path = 'include/SugarObjects/implements/' . $template . '/vardefs.php';
            if(file_exists($path)){
                require($path);
                $templates[$template] = $vardefs;
            }
        }
    }
```

Really waiting for awesome responses.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file at the path `custom/include/SugarObjects/VardefManager.php` with the name `VardefManager.php` and in that file include your mail file it is `include/SugarObjects/VardefManager.php`.

Here you will create a class with same and and create a function with the name

```
static function addTemplate
```

with same the arguments pass in the main file. and override the method here with your custom code (as you want to add some lines of code in that).

This will be upgrade safe and will be workable to you.

Comment: Thank's man, I previously tried this. But VardefManager.php is also not worked from custom.

Comment: happy and waiting for you.. more what i got so far is `include/entryPoint.php` is requiring`VardeManager.php`.